# Spring Boot MariaDB Docker Connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm stuck with SQLNonTransientConnectionException in Spring Boot application with MariaDB database using docker.

Docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  stats-server:
    container_name: stats-server
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-statsserver
      context: ./stats-server
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    depends_on:
      - stats-db

  stats-db:
    container_name: stats-db
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "9091:3306"
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=stats
      - MARIADB_USER=stats_user
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=stats_password
```

application.properties

```
#port
server.port=9090

#MariaDB
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://stats-db:9091/stats
spring.datasource.username=stats_user
spring.datasource.password=stats_password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

After docker-compose up command I've got the SQLNonTransientConnectionException error:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=stats-db)(port=9091)(type=primary). Connection refused
```

Database container runs well.
With Intellij Idea I can connect by this url:

```
jdbc:mariadb://localhost:9091/stats
```

Answer (score 0):

my bad, should been use internal container port

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://stats-db:3306/stats
```